# Including Amazon affiliate link to Amazon homepage

Tags: amazon

I want a link on my Web site that sends the user to the Amazon homepage, but includes my affiliate code so that any subsequent purchases get credited to my account.  I have been browsing through the Amazon Associates portal and there only seems to be a way to link to a specific product.

I found this link on [daringfireball.net](http://daringfireball.net):

```
http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/redirect?tag=daringfirebal-20&path=subst/home/home.html
```

If I replace his affiliate code (`daringfirebal-20`) with mine, will this work?  is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [Amazon link builder tool](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/build-links/text/main.html) to generate links with your affiliate code.